# How to control interval in rxjs? - inactivate timer in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to implement a kind of "session timer" in angular app. It will logout user when (s)he don't click any key in a specified period. Everything goes ok, until first logout. After 2nd login, reset method of timer don't work. The user is logged out after the specified time, regardless of the action performed.

I made a demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-session-timer?embed=1&file=src/app/session-timer.service.ts)

Here is code of service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SessionTimerService {
  private readonly sessionTimer: Observable<number> = interval(10000); // 10 sec
  private sessionTimerController: Subject<void>;

  public constructor(private readonly router: Router) {}

  public initTimer(): void {
    this.sessionTimerController = new Subject<void>();
    this.sessionTimer
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        takeUntil(this.sessionTimerController)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log("logout");
        this.sessionTimerController.next();
        this.sessionTimerController.complete();
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
      });
  }

  public resetTimer(): void {
    if (this.sessionTimerController && !this.sessionTimerController.closed) {
      console.log("reset");
      this.sessionTimerController.next();
      this.sessionTimerController.complete();

      this.initTimer();
    }
  }

  public stopTimer(): void {
    if (this.sessionTimerController && !this.sessionTimerController.closed) {
      console.log("stop");
      this.sessionTimerController.next();
      this.sessionTimerController.complete();
    }
  }
}
```

`window.relaod()` is not good answer on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating two independent timers when you logging the second time because on first login is `this.sessionTimerController === null` and you check this condition:

1. inside `onMouseMove`.
2. inside `MainComponent`'s constructor.

Second problem is that method `initTimer()` doesn't check if there's already a timer going:

So before creating a new timer you can complete the previous one so you know there will be always just one:

```
private sessionTimerController: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

...

public initTimer(): void {
  console.log('initTimer');

  this.sessionTimerController.next();
  this.sessionTimerController.complete();
  this.sessionTimerController = new Subject<void>();
  ...
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-session-timer-yqdxco?file=src/app/session-timer.service.ts

In my opinion in your use-case it would be easier to get rid of the `Subject` completely because it's just making things complicated and use a single `Subscription` object to cancel any previous timers.

Comment: I wrapped next() and complete() in method so it looks better and cleaner. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

RXJS is powerful and you can `unsubscribe` an on going event so I manged to do just that in this solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-session-timer-jpkxnj

here is the service code

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SessionTimerService {

  savedSub: Subscription;

  public constructor(private readonly router: Router) {

  }

  public initTimer(): void {

    this.savedSub = of(true).pipe(delay(5000))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      this.savedSub.unsubscribe();
    })

  }

  public resetTimer(): void {
    if(this.savedSub){
    this.savedSub.unsubscribe();
    this.savedSub = null;
    this.initTimer();
    }
  }

  onDestroy(){
    if(this.savedSub){
    this.savedSub.unsubscribe();
    this.savedSub = null;
    }
  }


}
```

initTimer will wait 5 seconds.. when no thing can stop it it will logout
when the subscription reference you have is `unsubscriped` is gone and it wont fire.. 
on mouse click we will `unsubscribe` it and re run the timer from the start on.

but you need to unsubscribe or `null` the value of the subscription if the no one stopped the timer.. and that's why we made `onDestroy` to be called from the main component when `ngOnDestroy` work

```js
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sessionTimer.onDestroy();
  }
```

hope that can solve your problem.